# Amazon Marketplace Web Service not working....?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am using Amazon Marketplace Web Service php client Library Code.

I have configured all the required parameter like (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `MERCHANT_ID`, `MarketplaceId` etc.)

I want to use action of type submit feed, but when I run the code the response I get is:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult
>   the service documentation for details

I am using the amazon-submit.php file and I do not understand what is wrong with the code.

I have tried lot but not get any correct result, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the c# library -- I've already found a couple bugs in their code (e.g. the namespace doesn't match, breaking the xml deserialization)